# couchdb: update metadata on a document with attachments?

Tags: couchdb, attachment

If I have a CouchDB document with a handful of metadata fields and a 10MB attachment, is there a way to update the document and leave the attachment identical, w/o having to re-transmit the 10MB attachment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works as intended, send new document (with `_attachments` stubs and latest `_rev`) and it sholud work.

Unless, by metadata you mean `content_type` field of attachment stub, in that case it is not possible.

Comment: you can't modify the contents of _attachments (e.g content_type) with the exception that if you *remove* a key from the _attachments object, the attachment is actually removed from the doc.